# IText 7: Table Content is not getting displayed

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to create a pdf document using IText 7 in Java. However the table contents are not getting displayed in the pdf.

Code Snippet:

```
private void addReceiptDetails(Document doc) {
        Table table = new Table(2, true);
        table.addCell(new Cell().add("C1"));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add("C2"));
        for (TaxTypeModel taxType : sale.getTaxModel().getTaxTypeModelList()) {
            table.addCell(new Cell().add("C9"));
            table.addCell(new Cell().add("C10"));
        }
        table.addCell(new Cell().add("C3"));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add("C4"));

        table.addCell(new Cell().add("C5"));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add("C6"));

        table.addCell(new Cell().add("C7"));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add("C8"));

        doc.add(table);
        table.complete();
        doc.close();
    }
```

PDF Table Content:

[image]

Can somebody please help me out here. I am not sure what exactly is wrong here.

EDIT: I tried a code sample from [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-101-very-simple-table):

```
Table table = new Table(8);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            table.addCell("hi");
        }
        doc.add(table);
```

And this is also just creating empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue.

I ran your code with the obvious changes:

- I had to remove the `for` loop as I do not have any such `TaxTypeModel` here.
- I had to add instantiation code for the document.

I.e. like this:

```
try (   OutputStream result = new FileOutputStream("simpleTableRahulDevMishra.pdf");
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(result);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDocument)   )
{
    Table table = new Table(2, true);
    table.addCell(new Cell().add("C1"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().add("C2"));
    /*
    for (TaxTypeModel taxType : sale.getTaxModel().getTaxTypeModelList()) {
        table.addCell(new Cell().add("C9"));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add("C10"));
    }
    */
    table.addCell(new Cell().add("C3"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().add("C4"));

    table.addCell(new Cell().add("C5"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().add("C6"));

    table.addCell(new Cell().add("C7"));
    table.addCell(new Cell().add("C8"));

    doc.add(table);
    table.complete();
    doc.close();
}
```

The result looks like this in Adobe Reader:

[image: Screenshot]

The cause of your issues, therefore, is not in the code you provided. So please provide code which allows to reproduce your issue.

---

Trying to reproduce the issue with the other code sample

```
Table table = new Table(8);
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    table.addCell("hi");
}
doc.add(table);
```

also resulted in cells with content:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I spent an awful amount of time to resolve this issue. And I could resolve it just now.
I had to add `.setFontColor(Color.BLACK)` for every cell.
I was setting the page background image to LIGHT_GRAY and maybe thats the reason as to why the default color wasn't being visible.

Comment: *"I had to add `.setFontColor(Color.BLACK)` for every cell"* - I assume there is a simpler solution, perhaps you merely have to set the fill color to black at the right place...